# How to know if `script` command (which records terminal sessions as typescript) is already runing?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, util-linux

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59670930/is-there-a-way-to-know-if-the-script-command-is-running-in-the-current-bash-se/59671817#59671817) says that `script` adds the variable `SCRIPT` to the environment of the command it runs. I tried that but it doesn't seem to be working now.

This is what I have tried

```
ma08@IWeighHar:~/pro$ script foo.log
Script started, output log file is 'foo.log'.
ma08@IWeighHar:~/pro$ echo $SCRIPT

ma08@IWeighHar:~/pro$ exit
exit
Script done.
ma08@IWeighHar:~/pro$ echo $SCRIPT

ma07@IWeighHar:~/pro$
```

How to detect if the `script` command is already running in the current terminal session?

Due to the name of this command, googling regarding it is kind of a nightmare.

Comment: Looking through [the source](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/blob/master/term-utils/script.c) (and locally testing) it doesn't seem like `util-linux`'s `script` sets this environment variable. If you're in control of the execution, then you might want to try something like `SCRIPT=foo script ...` to set the variable yourself. BSD `script` (on macOS, anyway) does set this variable.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani Thanks for the feedback. Added what I have tried as an example.

Comment: @muru Thanks, that's a bummer. I will do that. Would be nice to have the builtin down the line.

Comment: Did you read the comments below the answer that recommends this? They explain which versions of `script` set the variable.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. I just saw the latest comment regarding different version of `script`. Good to know, thanks for pointing that to me. I guess I will have to stick to using a manual of detecting if I am using a `script` version without that feature.

Answer (score 2):

As a heuristic, you could check whether there's a process whose name is `script` has your terminal device opened:

```
if lsof -watc script "$(tty)" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
  echo I may very well be within a script session
fi
```

`tty` returns the path of the terminal opened on stdin. Some shells set the `$TTY` variable to the path of their controlling terminal. See also `$(ps -o tty= -p "$$")` to get the controlling terminal without the `/dev/` prefix.

Answer (score 2):

Since the variant or version of the `script` utility you use does not set the `SCRIPT` environment variable within the shell it starts, you can do so yourself.  In variants of the utility that sets this variable, it is set to the name of the output file.  The following is a short `bash` shell function that would mimic that behaviour:

```bash
script () {
    local outfile="${1:-typescript}"
    SCRIPT=$outfile command script "$outfile"
}
```

This function takes an optional single argument which is the pathname of the output typescript file.  If no argument is supplied (or it's empty), the name `typescript` is used as the output file.  The name of the output file is also available as `"$SCRIPT"` in the shell that the utility starts.

You would use this function like

```bash
script myfile
```

or as

```bash
script
```

Alternatively, to allow an arbitrary command at the end of the command line (requires that the first argument is the typescript output file and, just like with the above variation, does not allow for giving options to the real `script` command):

```bash
script () {
    local outfile="${1:-typescript}"
    shift
    SCRIPT=$outfile command script "$outfile" "$@"
}
```

You could use this as above, but you could also add a command to run:

```bash
script outfile mail -s testmail user@remote.host
```

Answer (score 1):

This will offer what you need:

```
#!/bin/sh

# placing into Creative Commons - may not be claimed for copyright by any other individual or corporation.
# free to use and replicate

BASE=`basename "${0}" ".sh" `
TMP="/tmp/tmp.$$.${BASE}"

if [ $# -ne 1 ] ; then  echo "\n Must provide current shell PID by referencing it with $$ on the command line.\n" ; exit 1 ; fi

MySHELL=$1

ps -ef >${TMP}.ps
### FORMAT
#username   37539    4819  0 15:47 pts/3    00:00:00 bash
#username   37572   37539  0 15:49 pts/3    00:00:00 script scriptLog.txt
#username   37573   37572  0 15:49 pts/4    00:00:00 bash -i

awk -v sPID="${MySHELL}" '{
    if( $2 == sPID ){
        print $3 ;
    } ;
}' <${TMP}.ps |
{   read sPPID
    awk -v sPPID="${sPPID}" '{
        if( $2 == sPPID ){
            n=index( $0, "script " ) ;
            if( n == 0 ){
                print "\t safe to use \"script\"." ; exit 0 ;
            }else{
                COMMAND=substr( $0, n ) ;
                printf("BUSY [%s]:  %s\n", sPPID, COMMAND ) ; exit 1 ;
            } ; 
        } ;
    }' <${TMP}.ps
}

exit 0
exit 0
exit 0
```

If script is already logging the current shell, it will return RC=1 and report like this:

```
BUSY [37572]:  script scriptLog.txt
```

Otherwise, RC=0 and will report like this:

```
        safe to use "script".
```